# weird semantic issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I keep getting this semantic issue from the time i change from xcode 3 to 4

my code worked without any problem, but this keep coming when i'm using xcode 4...

: **Assigning to 'Main *' from incompatible type 'NSString *';**

How do i fix it? i tried remove: "   self.delegate=[[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease]; "

but removing it... is not a really fix

```
-(id)init {
    if (self=[super init])
    {

        self.delegate=[[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];


    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: A string can't be a delegate normally... where is your delegate declared?

Comment: so what should a do to remove the warning , how to fix it? the delegate is declared inside Hover.h

Comment: How is `delegate` defined?  (It's hard to imagine that a string would be useful.)

Comment: Don't use a string as a delegate? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The literal answer is that you should use an object of whatever class `delegate` is defined as and assign that instead of the string.  (Either pass it an existing object or create a new one, depending on the program logic.)

The **real** answer, though, would come from asking yourself: why is this delegate here and what is its purpose?